# string.split() is not working when passing it as argument to another function

Tags: python, string, split

My code:

```
testcases=int(input())
position=1
seconds=0
dictionary={1:".,;?", 2:"abc", 3:"def", 4:"ghi", 5:"jkl", 6:"mno", 
               7:"pqrs", 8:"tuv", 9:"wxyz", 0:" " }


def calculation(array,position):
    s=0
    print(array) # Here array shows ['1 2']
    for string in array:
        for character in string:
            if character in str(dictionary.keys()):
                if position==int(character):
                    s+=1
                else:
                    position=int(character)
                    s+=2
                print(position)
                #break
       
     return s

for test in range(testcases):
    string=input()
    if string.isspace()==False:
        seconds=calculation([string],position)
    else:
        seconds=calculation(string.split(),position) #Suppose my string="1 2"
```

Suppose I give `"1 2"` as input, then when I print the string in the function `calculation()`, the string shows as `['1 2']` instead of `['1', '2']`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Here `[string]` would form a list of the only element `string`. Maybe you have to call like if `.isspace()` is True instead:

```
if string.isspace():
    seconds=calculation([string],position)
else:
    seconds=calculation(string.split(),position)
```

Comment: But I want the string to be splitted, only if there's a space.

Comment: Did you read the definition of isspace in the docs? isspace returns True if all characters in the string are whitespace characters.

Comment: BTW, you don't even need the `if...else` block. Try `print('1'.split())` and `print('1 2 3'.split())` to see why.